# ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name (SQLSTATE 42601)

Tags: database, postgresql, go, struct, database-migration

I have tried everything within my power it is not still working, so here i am sharing the code

I am trying to store data in the database, using the user struct as the model and the userWallet as a child relating to the user struct, but i guess the SQL database stores them as different entity and returns error

it create the user wallet data first and then try to insert the user which throws up error

Error Message :

**2023/03/07 04:39:44 authentications.go:210 ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name (SQLSTATE 42601)
[0.667ms] [rows:0] INSERT INTO "user_wallets" ("uid","wallet_id","currency_id","currency","address","wallet_mail","destination_tag","total_payments") VALUES (43,'random','random','currency','','random@example.com','','0.0') ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE SET "uid"="excluded"."uid"**

**2023/03/07 04:39:44 authentications.go:210 ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name (SQLSTATE 42601)
[2.987ms] [rows:1] INSERT INTO "users" ("user_type","first_name","last_name","phone_number","email","username","password","confirm_password","asset","created_at","updated_at") VALUES ('USER','random','random','+randomNumber','random@example.com','random','PasswordHash','PasswordHash','currency','2023-03-07 04:39:44.427','2023-03-07 04:39:44.427') RETURNING "id"
2023/03/07 04:39:44 ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name (SQLSTATE 42601)**

this is how it tries inserting the data, **Seperately** not as one

**This is the project model / struct**

```golang
type User struct {
    ID              uint        `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
    Avatar          *Avatar     `json:"avatar,omitempty" gorm:"foreignKey:UID;reference:ID"`
    UserType        *string     `json:"userType,omitempty" validate:"eq=USER|eq=ADMIN"`
    FirstName       *string     `json:"firstName" validate:"required,gte=2"`
    LastName        *string     `json:"lastName" validate:"required,gte=2"`
    PhoneNumber     *string     `json:"phoneNumber" validate:"required"`
    Email           *string     `json:"email" gorm:"unique" validate:"required,email"`
    Username        *string     `json:"username" gorm:"unique" validate:"required"`
    Password        *string     `json:"password" validate:"required,gte=8"`
    ConfirmPassword *string     `json:"confirmPassword" validate:"required,gte=8"`
    Asset           *string     `json:"asset" validate:"required"`
    UserWallet      *UserWallet `json:"userWallet" gorm:"foreignKey:UID;references:ID;constraint:OnUpdate:CASCADE,OnDelete:SET NULL;"`
    CreatedAt       time.Time
    UpdatedAt       time.Time
}

// ID             uint   `json:"id" gorm:"primaryKey"`
type UserWallet struct {
    UID            uint   `json:"-"`
    WalletId       string `json:"WalletId"`
    CurrencyId     string `json:"currencyId"`
    Currency       string `json:"currency"`
    Address        string `json:"address"`
    WalletMail     string `json:"walletMail"`
    DestinationTag string `json:"destinationTag"`
    TotalPayments  string `json:"totalPayments"`
}
```

**this is the migration file**

```golang
func DatabaseConn() {
    var err error

    dsn := os.Getenv("DATABASEINFO")
    DB, err = gorm.Open(postgres.Open(dsn), &gorm.Config{},&gorm.Config{
        DisableForeignKeyConstraintWhenMigrating: true,
    })

    if err != nil {
        log.Println("[ERROR] : Error while connecting to database")
        log.Panic(err)
    }

    log.Println("Connecting to Database ")


    // Migrate the users table
    DB.AutoMigrate(&models.User{})
    log.Println("Successfully Connected to Database ")
}
```

Error message :

> 2023/03/07 04:39:44 [Recovery] 2023/03/07 - 04:39:44 panic recovered:
> ERROR: ON CONFLICT DO UPDATE requires inference specification or constraint name (SQLSTATE 42601)

i still dont get why it isnt working

i was expecting it to take in the data from the API posted and save in database

Comment: You should include the code that actually produces the error you are trying to solve. You should also put some effort into formatting the question so that it is readable by those from whom you expect help.

Comment: Including an error message and an indication where in the code it is thrown is helpful too.

Comment: @mkopriva I already reformat the question, can you please help me look into it ?